# Is Chromium Local Storage an alternative to node-keytar in electron?

Tags: passwords, local-storage, electron

I've to save user passwords on my electron app. https://github.com/atom/node-keytar is the best choice and it works well on Mac. But, a bulk of my user base is on Windows. KeyTar on windows is buggy and sometimes even insecure https://github.com/atom/node-keytar/issues/88.

So, I'm considering using chromium local storage (within electron) to store the  password - perhaps, salted/hashed.

I searched much of the relevant internet; no one has a blog/suggestion/SO post on this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I am about to implement electron's safeStorage which has been an option since Electron 15, so you likely were not able to benefit from it when you wrote this question. Regardless. Replying in case others look at this like I did in search of answers.
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/safe-storage